# Undefined navigation object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to build navigations between different views of a React-Native mobile app.
However, my navigation object (to run navigation.navigate) is always null. Thus, whenever I click on "connexion" or "Inscription", it throws the following error:

```
TypeError, undefined is not an object (evaluating "navigation.navigate")
```

**My files:**

1. package.json (list dependencies)
2. App_Default.js (entry point. Redirect to the landing page landing.js)
3. Three views. **(the issue is in landing.js)**
4. The Navigation configuration (Navigation.js)

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2"
  },
```

App_Default.js (my entry file, working as expected.)

```js
import React from "react";
import Landing from "./app/views/landing";

export default function App() {
  return <Landing />;
}
```

./app/views/landing.js

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Navigator from "../Navigation";

export default function Landing({ navigation }) {
  console.log(navigation);
  const pressHandler = (screen) => {
    navigation.navigate(screen);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.connexion}
        onPress={() => pressHandler("ConnectToApp")}
      >
        <Text>Connexion</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => pressHandler("Signup")}
        style={styles.signup}
      >
        <Text>Inscription</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  connexion: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    bottom: "20.625%",
    borderRadius: 8,
    left: "5.2%",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    width: 156,
    height: 52,
  },
  signup: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    bottom: "20.625%",
    borderRadius: 8,
    right: "5.2%",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    width: 156,
    height: 52,
  },
});
```

./app/views/connect_to_app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function ConnectToApp() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Signup</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

./app/views/Signup.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Signup</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

And finally, the Navigator:
Navigation.js

```js
// Navigation/Navigation.js

import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import ConnectToApp from "./views/connect_to_app";
import Signup from "./views/Signup";
import Landing from "./views/landing";

const screens = {
  ConnectToApp: {
    screen: ConnectToApp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "ConnectToApp",
    },
  },
  Signup: {
    screen: Signup,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Inscription",
    },
  },
  Landing: {
    screen: Landing,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Landing",
    },
  },
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);
export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Comment: try to update react-navigation to v5

Comment: My code is baded on: https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-native-tutorial/tree/lesson-21 which is not v5 for react-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly using the Landing screen in the App.js but you are setting up navigation in Navigator.js.

You should import Navigation in app.js and use like below

```
import Navigator from "../Navigation";

export default function App() {
  return <Navigator/>;
}
```

If this is a new App better upgrade to Navigation V5.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do that, it means i can't use the design of my landing page, i need to keep the Navigator design, which I don't want. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by design of the navigator?, the landing page is part of your stack navigator, you can set it as the initialRouteName and then it would be displayed as the first screen

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as the answer if all good :)